# why cant it detect FSCalendar in Swift

Tags: swift, fscalendar

first of all, im a very newbie to Swift language, I believe, FSCalendar is properly downloaded under my project, but when trying to use the class, it doesn't detect on custom class.

First, I created podfile and add pod 'FSCalendar' on it, and did pod install and everything seemed to go under the project.

second, I dragged and dropped FSCalendar to the project as it seems in the image below and made a view under main view defining custom class 'FSCalendar' and it just shows the FSCalendar designable,

every FSCalendar related classes display on drop down option of custom class, but it just doesnt detect it.

I would appreciate your help in advance, ive been struggling with the initial setting so long

thank you.

here is a screenshot of xcode screen
[image]

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: @burnsi got no error message, it just does not detect the class

Comment: Expand the `Pods` and `Frameworks` nodes in the Project explorer. Are one or more of the depencies names in red? Also when you click on the red sign in the top bar. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

So this is due to the fact that when you do `pod init` it creates an `.xcworkspace` file which you should now be using. This has a similar symbol to the normal `.xcodeproj` file you'd normally open, except its white, here's a screenshot of what it should look like:

[image: xcworkspace icon image]